# Show a sliding window (Bottom to top) on swipe

Tags: android, swipe, slidingmenu

Hi i downloaded some code from this [link](http://coderzheaven.com/uploads/PopUpAnimation.rar) in this code when clicking the image button "i" it's going to up and when clicking the "X" image it's going down, But i need to open this pop up on swipe (bottom to up) and again i want to close when we swipe (top to bottom). For this requirement i used

```
  setOnDragListener
  setOnTouchListener
```

But i did't get the result according to my requirement and i am also searching for solution from morning but i didn't get the solution. So, please help me.

For code [see this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/22/how-to-show-a-sliding-window-from-below-in-android/)

Comment: For other details see these images [Image 1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91846918/Sliding%20animation/device12.png), [Image 2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91846918/Sliding%20animation/device23.png)

Comment: Try this library [Android Sliding Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)